# java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.apache.bsf.BSFManager not in JAR file selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I install java latest version 18.0.2 still not able to run my selenium program, when i am adding jar to classpath it automatically adding to module path then getting error while running the program

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stacktrace.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.